# webpack for multiple express instances?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have an application that creates multiple express servers each acting as endpoints at the same time.
Each of them serve a react app that relies on the api from the that particular express server.
How do i use webpack to compile the react app and serve for the particular instance of the app for each express server .
As each react app relies on the endpoint of that instance of express the port number differs.
which i need to communicate to react app through webpack .
Also how do i run webpack when i npm start my server.

Comment: are you asking about environmental configuration?  you can do that many ways, and webpack doesn't necessarily need to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to replace identifiers in your webpacked code with anything, like a port number.

In your `"start"` script, you could do `"webpack -w & <however you start your server>"`, however I would recommend separating the two steps and having two different npm scripts for `build` and `start`.